# Neo4j: Find nodes which has connections to ALL nodes in a list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have a match query which returns a list of nodes (oms), and next I match nodes (rs) which are related to (oms), but I only want them if the single node of (rs) has a relation to ALL or MORE of the list I returned earlier (oms). Here is what my query looks like:

```
MATCH (st:Route) WHERE id(st) = 0
MATCH (st)--(rs:RS)--(oms:OMS)
WITH st,rs, collect(oms) AS omsList

MATCH (ed:Route)--(rs2:RS)
WHERE ALL(x in omsList WHERE (rs2)--(x))
UNWIND omsList AS oms

RETURN *
```

And this is what my query gives:

[image: Query results]

But as explained from above, I do not want nodes 20 and 21 because they do not have a relation to ALL of the nodes returned from the list.

Note I start from node 0 which ends with the (oms) nodes 4 and 2. So I only want them if they have relations to BOTH 4 AND 2.

How would I query this the way I want to?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that your query is right. I think your issue is related to a Neo4j Browser visualization feature called "Connect result nodes". When this feature is enabled, Neo4j browser will connect the resultant nodes in the graph visualization mode when a connection between these nodes exist.

To disable this behavior you should go to the section "Graph Visualization" of Neo4j Browser Settings and uncheck the option "Connect result nodes" as shown in the image below:

[image: Graph visualization option]

Comment: But if if the results were correct, shouldn't node 21 and 20 be filtered out by `WHERE ALL(x in omsList WHERE (rs2)--(x))`?

To get down to the basics, say i have 2 nodes, i want to return all nodes that have relations to *BOTH* of them.

Comment: Hi, @JiahaoZhao sorry for my late answer. Yes, your result is correct. But as I said, your issue is probably related to a visualization option. Try disabling "connect result nodes" or changing the visualization mode to "Text" in Neo4j Browser.

Comment: Seeing this about 3 years late as I had a similar question. The reason you are getting Nodes 20 and 21 is because of your RETURN * which is returning all variables in scope at that point in the query. That’s how your omsList is getting returned.